# How to get VS to display Git commit message template

Tags: git, visual-studio

This is more of a two part question, as follows:

1) How do I set `commit.template` to be relative to the Git working directory? I had a look here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration, but the example in there sets the path to `~/` which is the user's home directory. I need the template file itself to be version controlled.

2) How do I get Visual Studio 2017 to load the template? Regardless of whether I choose `--global` or `--local` when setting the Git config, I don't see my template in the commit message entry box. I do however see it if I execute `git commit` via command line.

Comment: I think I have the answer for the first one: the file path needs to be on the root of your repository. Example: `git config commit.template src/myrepo/.gitmessage`. I managed to accept it that way and it doesn't throw the 'file not found error any more'. However, I'm stuck on your #2 question as well.